# If two cells match and third cell equals specific value the return the value in the fourth cell

Tags: excel, compare, match

I would like to compare three cells and return the third value in the fourth cell.

If column A has a match in cell B2 and cell C2 = 1 then I want to return the value of D2 in E2. Is there anyway to do this?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,A:A,0)),C2=1),D2,"No Match")
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you so much. Saved me hours of work

Comment: If it worked for you please mark the answer as "Selected".